# java - nio: send from different thread than selecting

Tags: java, multithreading, server, nio, throughput

I have often heard that it is considered "good design" to have a single thread that's in charge of all communication with the clients.

Now I have, however, multiple threads that communicate with other servers to handle a client request.

The current design will enqueue the response to send for the selecting thread. The selecting thread then dequeues the responses and sends them to the appropriate client.

This is stupid, imo. I have like 30 threads ready to send responses to the clients and they all enqueue them and let the one selecting thread send them one by one.

Assuming a closed system, is there no way to safely bypass this limitation and send from a thread that doesn't have a (or if he does not the same) selector as the thread that originally accepted the client request? If so, how?

Comment: A server usually serves each client within an own thread. If you heard something else then I would consider it as a rumour which is wrong.

Comment: @Heri It is no rumour. Clearly you have never heated of non-blocking multiplexed I/O, which is what the question is about. It was introduced into Java 1.4 in the `java.nio` package in about 2002, and had been present in Unix and Windows and other operating system for decades previously. Don't post misinformation here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Assuming a closed system, is there no way to safely bypass this limitation

There is no such limitation. You can send from any thread you like.

> and send from a thread that doesn't have a (or if he does not the same) selector as the thread that originally accepted the client request? If so, how?

Just call `SocketChannel.write()`. The only time you need to enqueue writes to the selector thread is if you get a short or zero length write, in which case the channel needs to be registered for OP_WRITE, the data enqueued, etc.